# Did people trigger the White Island 2019 eruption?

Tags: volcanology, geography

I am writing an essay about [White Island’s 2019 eruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whakaari_/_White_Island#2019_eruption), and I need to know if the eruption was directly triggered by people. Is it possible that it was? Whether it being quarrying, too much tourism etc.?